# Why Doesn't my SQL Server Database Connection Refresh via Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, sqlconnection, vba

I have a report I am building from data I have in my SQL Server Database.
I have 3 connections to the 3 different tables in the Database.

I have 2 worksheets in my excel Report.

```
Sheet 1 = Report
Sheet 2 = Data
```

I have the following simple macro to fire at the 'Workbook_Open' event:

```
Public Sub Refresh_Connection()

    'Wait for all Refresh Procedures to finish
    'This procedure will refresh the Connection to the database
    wsData.Activate

    Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
        wsData.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("KDSU513_JASONR dw_test Virtual_Bed_Board_Query_ChartData").refresh
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("KDSU513_JASONR dw_test Virtual_Bed_Board_Query_SummaryData").refresh
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("KDSU513_JASONR dw_test Virtual_Bed_Board_Query_AdmitData").refresh

        DoEvents
    Loop
    wsReport.Activate

End Sub
```

Originally I was getting a message saying the Refresh wasn't complete so I had added a Wait similar to:

```
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:15 AM#)
```

However I think this process stops everything from happening including the Database Refresh.  I feel like this should be so so simple but I'm missing something stupid.

I have tried so many different methods but for some reason my Database Connection is not getting refreshed.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the Solution to this, at least in SQL Server.
It has nothing to do with the Macro, you have to turn off "enable background refresh" for each connection you are working with.

Go to the data tab, click connections in the connections group, R-click on Your  connection(s) and click properties. Un-check the box that says "enable background refresh.  I also added an extra line of:
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Just to be on the safe side, not working lots of data so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The `Refresh` method has a `BackgroundQuery` argument that you can set to False, but `RefreshAll` does not. Also, you can loop through all your querytables and set the `QueryTable.BackgroundQuery` property to False in code.